# Jquery Sortable table scroll issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Hello guys,
Im using jquery sortable table, but scroll not working, please check the link,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('tbody').sortable({
     items: 'tr',
     handle: '.is-sortable',
     cursor: 'move',
     opacity: 0.6,
     placeholder: 'success',
     axis: 'y',
     scroll: true,
     scrollSensitivity: 80,
     scrollSpeed: 3,
     helper: function(e, ui) {
       ui.children().each(function() {
         $(this).width($(this).width());
       });
       return ui;
     },
     update: function(e, ui) {
     }
   }).on('scroll', function() {
     console.log('scroll');
   }).disableSelection();
   
 });
```

Please check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/dxvndt6o/

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'scroll not working'? The sort and scroll appears to work fine in your fiddle (using latest Chrome on W10)

Comment: scroll is working fine in the fiddle

Comment: i have latest chrome, when i drag "SOme Name 1" to bottom i cannot move since scroll bar is still and not scrolling with cursor